# I can't scape a particular sentence in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have the following problem.
I am creating a playbook in Ansible for the installation of OCSInventory, at the time of executing the script the interaction begins to define certain parameters, for this I have used the Expect module, within these questions there is one in particular that I cannot successfully create the escape of the characters, then I share the information.

**Although originally they use single quotes, you have to assign double quotes, according to the message delivered by the ansible log**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXYlY.png)

'To ensure Apache loads mod_perl before OCS Inventory NG Communication Server,Setup can name Communication Server Apache configuration file ""z-ocsinventory-server.conf"" instead of ""ocsinventory-server.conf"". Do you allow Setup renaming Communication Server Apache configuration file to ""z-ocsinventory-server.conf"" ([y]/n) \?': ''

**And this is the mistake, I tried different ways, without results, if someone could give me some advice.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeMtP.png)

```
  "+----------------------------------------------------------------------+", 
    "|     OK, Communication server plugins Perl directory created ;-)      |", 
    "|                                                                      |", 
    "|               Now configuring Apache web server...                   |", 
    "+----------------------------------------------------------------------+", 
    "", 
    "To ensure Apache loads mod_perl before OCS Inventory NG Communication Server,", 
    "Setup can name Communication Server Apache configuration file", 
    "'z-ocsinventory-server.conf' instead of 'ocsinventory-server.conf'.", 
    "Do you allow Setup renaming Communication Server Apache configuration file", 
    "to 'z-ocsinventory-server.conf' ([y]/n) ?"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lookup plugin to load tricky text into variables.

```
vars:
  prompt: '{{ lookup("file", "tricky_prompt.txt") }}'
```

Save the text you want to load into `files/tricky_prompt.txt`.

Than just use variable `prompt` everywhere you need your text.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know what you mentioned, I will try this solution